# How to evaluate the same code in a whole bunch of existing notebooks

Tags: files-and-directories, notebooks

I have a large folder of existing notebooks, each currently containing a single cell of input. I would like --- in each of these notebooks --- to evaluate that cell, evaluate a new chunk of code I've written (whose purpose is to `Export` a text file and an image created from the data in the notebook), and re-save the notebook.

How can I do this in an automated way for the whole folder of files?

*[Note: Each notebook has the same variables defined, but I have `Notebook's Default Context` set to `Unique to This Notebook`, so there should be no conflicts.]*

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to achieve?  Are you trying to modify those notebooks, add some text to them?  Are you aware that kernel state is not local to notebooks?  If you do `a=1` in a notebook, then `a==1` is `True` in all.  Notebooks are just containers of text.

Comment: I have `Notebook's Default Context` set to `Unique to This Notebook`

Comment: The code I want to run in each notebook includes several `Export` statements. So I want to evaluate the existing code in the notebook (which is in a single cell), then run my new code (which exports an image and a text file).

Comment: Please edit these clarifications into the original question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any better?

Comment: Yes.  You don't need to mark your edits since almost no one has seen this question yet.  The point is that to maximize your chances for a useful answer the question should be *self-contained* (not rely on comments or links) and *easy to read/understand*.

Comment: Have you tried working with `NotebookEvaluate` ? I'd suggest you take a stab at it and see what problems you run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather simplistically, define a function to add the required cell to the end and evaluate a Notebook:

```
updateNotebook[file_] := 
 Module[{nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[Directory[], file]]}, 
  SelectionMove[nb, After, Notebook];
  NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Plot[Cos[y],{y,1,10}]", "Input"]];
  NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
  NotebookSave[nb];
  NotebookClose[nb]; file]
```

Then map this function to a list of the Notebooks in your folder:

```
updateNotebook /@ FileNames["path/to/folder/*.nb"];
```

This is just an outline which should be improved with error checks, obviously replacing `Plot[...]` with the actual code you wish to add.

Comment: Playing with this now, thanks. Is the only purpose of the final `file` to produce some visible evidence of having done something?

Comment: @thecommexokid, yes, I felt a list of `Null`s wasn't too informative.

Comment: I have it working great. One important modification I made was to add `Visible -> False` to the `NotebookOpen` command; otherwise it was seizure-inducing to watch!